# My Azure AKS Service not able to access from Internet

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I've deployed a pod in AKS and I'm trying to connect to my service through a public IP.
When I check my service from kubectl command or K8 dashboard, my deployments are successful.
Service and Pod are running perfectly.

When I want to  access my public IP with port, my service is not responding.
My public IP and port are already displayed in the correct Azure Network Security Group.

Do I need add any additional settings in Azure side?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sample-service
        image: container/sample-service:#{Build.BuildId}#
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: sample-service
      dnsPolicy: xxxxx
      restartPolicy: Always
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: sample-service
```

Comment: Can you share the YAML file you used to deploy the pod and service?

Comment: No, you need additional settings on the k8s side. You need to expose your service through an ingress controller of some sort. Please provide your yaml pod and service definitions.

Comment: @Software Engineer that is incorrect. While the Ingress system can be helpful, it is not required and you can just use LoadBalancer or NodePort services directly.

Comment: It's not incorrect, just incomplete :) It's not meant to be a full answer, just a remark about the easiest thing he can do.

Comment: Charles...Please find YAML file

Comment: @SrinivasaragavanR can you please place those yamls into the question?

Comment: Do you solve the problem? Or need more help? Please let me know it.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Or what's more do you want?

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, the possible reason is that you did not set the `targetPort` in the service. So you could try to change the service like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: sample-service
  selector:
    app: sample-service
```

Then re-create the service again.

Comment: I tried the same way. Still I am getting same issue. When I ping public IP I am getting timeout....

Comment: In Azure, Network group I am able to see the new Public IP as Inbound Rule...But still my service is not opening in browser

Comment: @SrinivasaragavanR You do not need to care about the Network group, Azure set the rules for you. Can you share the pod state? And you can also take a port-forward for the pod to check if the pod works fine.

Comment: Pod status is Running

Comment: @SrinivasaragavanR Do you test the port-forward for the pod?

Comment: @SrinivasaragavanR  Take a look at the steps [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod).